# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'start_time'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have `ChapterMarks` class in my `models.py` with a foreign key that comes from `Production` class. I am trying to use the info I submit in `ChapterMarks` in my `views.py` so the user can continue with the episode setup. In this section it requires that the user can input start times for each of their sections in their podcast so the customer can click and take them to certain time stamps. The problem is I am getting the following `AttributeError`:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.33.10:8000/fc/episodechaptermarks/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('producer',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'registration',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'storages',
 'django_extensions',
 'randomslugfield',
 'adminsortable2',
 'crispy_forms')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py" in dispatch
  56.         return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vagrant/fullcast_project/producer/views/views.py" in get
  738.             initial_values['start_time'] = chaptermark.start_time

Exception Type: AttributeError at /fc/episodechaptermarks/
Exception Value: 'int' object has no attribute 'start_time'
```

**Error is located under `get` method in my `ChapterMarks` class in `views.py`:** `initial_values['start_time'] = chaptermark.start_time`

Any suggestion welcome

**Here is my `ChapterMarks` class in `views.py`:**

```
class EpisodeChapterMarksView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    form_class = EpisodeChapterMarksForm
    template_name = 'fc/forms_chapter_marks.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        initial_values = {}
        user = request.user


        client, podcast = get_fc_client_and_podcast_for_user(user)
        if client is None or podcast is None:
            raise Http404

        production = Production.objects.filter(podcast=podcast).first()

        if production is None:
             raise Http404

        initial_values['production_id'] = production.id
        chaptermark_id = production.id

        if chaptermark_id is not None:
            chaptermark = production.id
            initial_values['chaptermark_id'] = chaptermark_id
            initial_values['start_time'] = chaptermark.start_time
            initial_values['title'] = chaptermark.title

        form = self.form_class(initial=initial_values)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        client, podcast = get_fc_client_and_podcast_for_user(request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            # lets get the data
            production_id = form.cleaned_data.get('production_id')
            chaptermark_id = form.cleaned_data.get('chaptermark_id')
            start_time = form.cleaned_data.get('start_time')
            title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')

            # Get production
            production = get_object_or_404(Production, id=production_id)

            # if a chaptermark existed, we update, if not we create
            if chaptermark_id is not None:
                chaptermark = ChapterMark.objects.get(id=chaptermark_id)
            else:
                chaptermark = ChapterMark()

            chaptermark.start_time = start_time
            chaptermark.title = title
            chaptermark.save()

            production.chapter_mark = chaptermark
            production.save()

            # TODO: Needs to redirect to next step
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('fc:episodeshowlinks'))

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**`Production` and `ChapterMark` class in my `models.py`:**

```
    class Production(TimeStampedModel):
    BASE_PRODUCTION = 'B'
    SECONDARY_PRODUCTION = 'S'

    podcast = models.ForeignKey(Podcast, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    ready_for_production = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    episode_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    episode_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    episode_guest_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    episode_guest_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    episode_guest_twitter_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    episode_summary = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)

    base_production_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    base_production_status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    base_production_produced = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    base_production_started = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    base_production_cover_image = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    square_image_file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

    secondary_production_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    secondary_production_status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    secondary_production_produced = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    secondary_production_started = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    secondary_production_cover_image = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    banner_image_file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

    auphonic_result_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    soundcloud_result_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    youtube_result_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    libsyn_result_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    spreaker_result_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    spreaker_result_id_request_attempted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    source_file_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
    source_file_image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    output_base_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)

    scheduled_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    fully_produced_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    auto_email_sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    post_to_wordpress = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    wordpress_post_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    wordpress_slug = models.CharField(max_length=127, null=True, blank=True)
    wordpress_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    wordpress_short_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    wordpress_featured_image = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    wordpress_featured_image_upload = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    wordpress_post_unique_tags = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    wordpress_posting_failure_notified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    transcription_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)

    tweets_already_scheduled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    number_of_refresh_tweets = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    tweets_scheduling_failure_notified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_text(self.base_production_episode_title())

    def fully_produced(self):
        return self.base_production_produced and self.secondary_production_produced
    fully_produced.short_description = 'Produced'

    def status(self):
        if not self.fully_produced():
            return 'Pending'
        if self.wordpress_url:
            return 'Published'
        return 'Produced'

    def episode(self):
        return self.episode_number

    def base_production_episode_title(self):
        return self._title_string_for_format(self.podcast.base_production_name_format)

    def secondary_production_episode_title(self):
        return self._title_string_for_format(self.podcast.secondary_production_name_format)

    def _title_string_for_format(self, title_format):
        from producer.helpers import replace_placeholder_in_text_format_with_parameter

        guest_name = self.episode_guest()
        episode_number = str(self.episode_number).zfill(3)
        episode_title = self.episode_title

        title = replace_placeholder_in_text_format_with_parameter(title_format, 'EPISODE_GUEST_FULL_NAME', guest_name)
        title = replace_placeholder_in_text_format_with_parameter(title, 'EPISODE_NUMBER', episode_number)
        title = replace_placeholder_in_text_format_with_parameter(title, 'EPISODE_TITLE', episode_title)

        return title

    def episode_guest(self):
        if self.episode_guest_last_name and self.episode_guest_first_name:
            return '%s %s' % (self.episode_guest_first_name, self.episode_guest_last_name)

        if self.episode_guest_last_name:
            return self.episode_guest_last_name

        if self.episode_guest_first_name:
            return self.episode_guest_first_name

        return ''
```

**-------------------------------------------------**

```
class ChapterMark(TimeStampedModel):
production = models.ForeignKey(Production)
start_time = models.TimeField()
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
url = models.URLField(blank=True)
image_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)

def start_time_string(self):
    return self.start_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

def wordpress_start_time_string(self):
    string = self.chapter_timestamp()
    return string if string else '-:-'

def link(self):
    if self.url:
        return '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>' % (self.url, self.url)
    return
link.allow_tags = True

def __unicode__(self):
    return u''

def chapter_timestamp(self):
    if self.start_time:
        if self.start_time.hour > 0:
            return self.start_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        return self.start_time.strftime('%M:%S')
    return
```

**`chapter_marks.py` form:**

```
from django import forms

class EpisodeChapterMarksForm(forms.Form):

    production_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget, required=False)

    id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget)

    chaptermark_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget, required=False)
    start_time = forms.TimeField()
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**-------------UPDATE-------------**

New error:

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.33.10:8000/fc/episodechaptermarks/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('producer',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'registration',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'storages',
 'django_extensions',
 'randomslugfield',
 'adminsortable2',
 'crispy_forms')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py" in dispatch
  56.         return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vagrant/fullcast_project/producer/views/views.py" in get
  738.             chaptermark = production.chaptermark_set.get(id=chaptermark_id).id

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  387.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /fc/episodechaptermarks/
Exception Value: ChapterMark matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
chaptermark = production.chapter_mark
```

to

```
chaptermark = production.chaptermark_set.get(id=chaptermark_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Still getting an `AttributeError`. Updated my question with the log in the bottom.

Comment: @wlmrlsda as I said, you cannot do `production.chapter_mark_id` since production doesnot have OneToOne key in this direction. you can do `chaptermark_id = production.chaptermark_set.get(id=chaptermark_id).id`

Comment: So, instead of having `chaptermark_id = production.chapter_mark_id`, I replaced it with `chaptermark_id = production.id` and also replaced `chaptermark = production.chapter_mark` with `chaptermark_id = production.chaptermark_set.get(id=chaptermark_id).id` inside `if chaptermark_id is not None:` And got `DoesNotExist` error saying `ChapterMark matching query does not exist.` You can check update for the error log.

Answer (score 0):

in doniyor version you have to make

```
chaptermark = production.chaptermark_set.get(id=chaptermark_id) 
chaptermark.start_time
```

and you'll get the value.
If you want to get value in one step of start_time you can try

```
chaptermark = production.chaptermark_set.values('start_time')[0]['start_time']
```

Please note that you have same problem with the second attribute - 'title'

Comment: So inside of `if chaptermark_id is not None:` only add `chaptermark = production.chaptermark_set.values('start_time')[0]['start_time']`? By the way, the line before this `if` statement (`chaptermark_id = production.cha[ter_mark_id`) I changed it to `chaptermark_id = production.id`.

Comment: initial_values['start_time'] = production.chaptermark_set.values('start_time')[0]['start_mark']

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to understand your code:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    initial_values = {}
    user = request.user

    client, podcast = get_fc_client_and_podcast_for_user(user)
    if client is None or podcast is None:
        raise Http404
```

so far so good...

```
    production = Production.objects.filter(podcast=podcast).first()
```

this is strange, why would you select first `Production` for specific podcast... if you have 1-to-1, then use `OneToOneField` if you have 1-to-many - there should be something to limit selection of the `Production` or you should return a list of all `Production` attached to podcast - so here is something shaky

```
    if production is None:
         raise Http404
```

ok, but there is "magic" `get_object_or_404` shortcut...

```
    initial_values['production_id'] = production.id
    chaptermark_id = production.id

    if chaptermark_id is not None:
        chaptermark = production.id
```

ok... you are assigning an `int` value to `chaptermark`

```
        initial_values['chaptermark_id'] = chaptermark_id
        initial_values['start_time'] = chaptermark.start_time
        initial_values['title'] = chaptermark.title
```

those two lines are trying to get properties of `chaptermark` but `chaptermark` is not your model object but `int` - it does not have those properties!

so it looks like you should assign (earlier) to `chaptermark` an instance of `ChapterMark`, however... `Production` may have a multiple `ChapterMark`s...
so which `ChapterMark` do you want to see?

This looks like another serious flow, because you have here 1-to-many and this can;t be represented in the `Form`, but as a dependant `FormSet` - with the list of the chapter-marks.

So there are fundamental errors in your approach!

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. Now, what I am trying to do is the following. User will have a `production` already created with the necessary info until this point. I would say it should be a `One-To-Many` since the user [will be creating several timestamps](http://imgur.com/fEn3ZNJ) to point out certain topics he talking throughout his podcast. With this in mind, should I still assign `chaptermark` earlier and use a `FormSet` instead of `Form`?

Comment: you see, you may have 2 options for one-to-many :D (1) you have one master record and multiple slave records but all slave records are relevant - in such a case you should think as master-detail form, where you have main `Form/ModelForm` and `FormSet/ModelFormSet` or (2) you have one master and multiple slave records but only one is important (e.g. latest version metadata) - then you can put everything in one `Form/ModelForm` and then in your code shuffle data between master record and one slave